# Ruby on Rails choosing wrong controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

Today I came across some strange (and very inconvenient) Ruby on Rails behavior that even persistent combing of the net did not yield a satisfying answer to.
Note: I translated the method and route names to be easier to read in English, and hope I did not introduce any inconsistencies.

## Situation

### Environment

Ruby on Rails 4.2.0 executing under Ruby 2.0 (also tested under Ruby 2.2.0)

### Relevant Code

consider a controller with these actions, among others:

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    ...
  end

  def takeover_confirmation
    ...
  end
end
```

### routes.rb

Since I use a lot of manually defined routes, I did *not* use resources in routes.rb. The routes in question are defined as follows:

```
...
post 'assignments/:id' => 'assignments#update', as: 'assignment'
post 'assignments/takeover_confirmation' => 'assignments#takeover_confirmation'
...
```

The relevant output of `rake routes`:

```
assignment POST  /assignments/:id(.:format)  assignments#update
assignments_takeover_confirmation  POST  /assignments/takeover_confirmation(.:format) assignments#takeover_confirmation
```

### Problem

When I do a POST to the `assignments_takeover_confirmation_path`, rails routes it to the `update` method instead. Server log:

```
Started POST "/assignments/takeover_confirmation" for ::1 at ...
Processing by AssignmentsController#update as HTML
```

### Mitigation

If I put the `update` route definition *after* the `takeover_confirmation` one, it works as intended (didn't check a POST to `update` though).

Furthermore, after writing all this I found out I used the wrong request type for the `update` method in routes.rb (POST instead of PATCH). Doing this in routes.rb does indeed solve my problem:

```
patch 'assignments/:id' => 'assignments#update', as: 'assignment'
```

However, even when defining it as POST, Rails should not direct a POST request to the existing path "/assignments/takeover_confirmation" to a completely different action, should it?
I fear the next time I use two POST routes for the same controller it will do the same thing again.

It seems I have a severe misconception of Rails routing, but cannot lay my finger on it...

## Edit: Solution

As katafrakt explained, the above request to `/assignments/takeover_confirmation` matched the route `assignments/:id` because Rails interpreted the "takeover_confirmation" part as string and used it for the :id parameter. Thus, this is perfectly expected behavior.

### Working Example

For the sake of completeness, here is a working (if minimalistic) route-definition that does as it should, inspired by Chris's comment:

```
  resources :assignments do
    collection do
      post 'takeover_confirmation'
    end
  end
```

In this example, only my manually created route is explicitly defined. The routes for update, show, etc. (that I defined manually at first) are now implicitly defined by `resources: :assignments`.

Corresponding excerpt from `rake routes`:

```
...
takeover_confirmation_assignments  POST  /assignments/takeover_confirmation(.:format) assignments#takeover_confirmation
...
assignment GET    /assignments/:id(.:format)  assignments#show
           PATCH  /assignments/:id(.:format)  assignments#update
           PUT    /assignments/:id(.:format)  assignments#update
           DELETE /assignments/:id(.:format)  assignments#destroy
....
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: maybe I missed something when reading your question, but why aren't you using `resources` in your routes file? ...ohhh I see your using a lot of manually defined routes.  Well what happens when you use `resources`? Do you get the desired behavior you are seeking?

Comment: trying to refactor that right now... will let you know how it works out.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited the "Solution" section and placed a working example there based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> However, even when defining it as POST, Rails should not direct a POST request to the existing path "/assignments/takeover_confirmation" to a completely different action, should it?

It should. Rails routing is matched in exact same order as defined in `routes.rb` file (from top to bottom). So if it matches a certain rule (and `/assignments/takeover_confirmation` matches `assignments/:id` rule) it stops processing the routing.

This behaviour is simple and efficient. I imagine that any kind of "smart" matching the best route would result in cumbersome and unexpected results.

BTW that's why catch-all route used to be defined at the very bottom of routing file.

Comment: ARGH! It never even occurred to me that you could interpret the string "takeover_confirmation" as a parameter and pass it as :id. In fact, this is exactly what happened later, when the line `Assignment.find params[:id]` in my update method complained about not finding an object with id "takeover_confirmation". So it was right to match the route like that - I was just not seeing it!

Comment: You could use constraints to avoid that. Like `post 'assignments/:id' => 'assignments#update', as: 'assignment', constraints: { id: /\d.+/ }`.

Comment: thanks, I did not know about this, and it might come in handy in similar situations. However, I think it is cleaner to avoid such ambiguity in the first place - after all, it was no problem after you explained _why_ it was happening at all.